# the set of all orthogonal matrix is disconnected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to solve the following problem:

The set of all ortogonal  matrix $ n \times n $ is  disconnected.

I would really appreciate your help with this problem thank you.

Comment: Hint: assuming you mean real orthogonal matrices, they will have determinant $\pm 1$; consider the union of the ones with determinant $1$ and the ones with determinant $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

let $ det : \mathbb M_{n \times n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R $ be the determinant function. This function is continuons and then carries connected sets in connected sets. 
The restriction of this function in the set of all ortogonal matrix is such that this image is the set $\{ -1, 1 \}$. But this set is disconnected.

I appreciate the suggestion given by the user Ian. Your suggestion helped me to solve this problem. thank you so much!

Comment: so you have a partition into two closed subsets $\det^{-1}( \pm 1)$. It's even more interesting to show that each of them is connected. The one $\det^{-1}(1)$ is also known as $SO(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: thank you  Orangeskid!